# Are there instructions for downloading and installing .NET Core 3.1 SDK on Linux Mint 19.3?

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, linux-mint

I’ve recently installed Linux Mint 19.3 Xfce on a machine and I’m fairly new to the Linux ecosystem.

I checked the [dotnet docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1910) and didn’t see any specific steps for Linux Mint. I’ve also came across a few blog posts [here](https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/linux-mint-19-and-dotnet-development/) and [here](https://www.christianengvall.se/visual-studio-code-asp-net-core-linux-mint/).

Am I able to use the steps for a different flavor of Linux from the docs that will work for Linux Mint 19.3?

As I said I’m still getting my feet wet with Linux, but want to make sure I get dotnet up and running correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux Mint 19.3 is based on a Ubuntu 18.04 distribution. It should be fine to follow the instructions of **Ubuntu 18.04 x64**. The installation is done via terminal and apt-get.

Taken from the doc:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Now you can install the sdk

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

Run in the terminal this command to check if the sdk has been correctly installed

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

You don't need to install the .Net Core Runtime since SDK includes it.